# PowerShell scripts that acts on both local AD and Azure objects

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell scripts that opens sessions to both our on-prem Exchange server and online Exchange server to manage distribution lists specific to each environment. Problem is, when running

Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "TestAzureGroup@domain.com" -Member "TestUser"

Which is a distribution list defined in online Exchange, it throws an error saying it can't find the list on our local AD.

Is it possible to specify which session to work on within the command? Or another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, if you add '-Prefix' to the Import-PSSession command, you remove name collision when you have multiple commands imported with the same name. For example,

```
Import-PSSession $LocalSession -AllowClobber -Prefix "Local"
Import-PSSession $AzureSession -AllowClobber -Prefix "Remote"
```

Creates two different Add-DistributionGroupMember commands, one called Add-LocalDistributionGroupMember and the other called Add-RemoteDistributionGroupMember so you can then work on both sessions at the same time using the two different command names.